# How do you send a 3d array in a GET request with Apache HTTP client?

Tags: java, get, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have to integrate with a so called REST API which isn't RESTFul at all. To add some more data to a specific GET request I have to send a 3d array in the URL (ugly!!). Does anybody know how to do this with the Apache HTTP client v4.0.1?

Here is a sample in PHP:

```
$arrArguments['saleData'] = array(); 
$arrArguments['saleData']['invoiceDate'] = 'abcdef';
$arrArguments['saleData']['deliveryDate'] = 'abcdef';
$arrArguments['saleData']['orderData'] = array(); 
$arrArguments['saleData']['orderData'][0] = array(); 
$arrArguments['saleData']['orderData'][0]['productId'] = 'abcdef';
$arrArguments['saleData']['orderData'][0]['description'] = 'abcdef';
$arrArguments['saleData']['orderData'][0]['price'] = 18819;
$arrArguments['saleData']['orderData'][0]['quantity'] = 24389;
$arrArguments['saleData']['orderData'][0]['vatCode'] = 'abcdef';;;;
```

Comment: you have to send this as a query? or as some other parameter?

Comment: Do you know how this array maps to URL query parameters? `?saleData[OrderData][0][productId]=abcef`?

Comment: I think it's just like you described. Do you know how to send these query parameters with the Apache HTTP client? Should I just add "saleData[OrderData][0][productId]" as the parameter name and then add a value or something?

Comment: Yes, if that is how the parameters look in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer was from Thilo. You can just add "saleData[OrderData][0][productId]" as parameter name and than specify the value. So you can have something like this:

```
final URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(apiUrl)
        .setPath(this.apiStartPath)
        .setParameter("saleData[OrderData][0][productId]", '12334')
        ......
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$arrArguments['saleData'] = array(); 
$arrArguments['saleData']['orderData'] = array(); 
$arrArguments['saleData']['orderData'][0] = array(); 

$arrArguments['saleData']['invoiceDate'] = 'abcdef';
$arrArguments['saleData']['deliveryDate'] = 'abcdef';

$arrArguments['saleData']['orderData'][0]['productId'] = 'abcdef';
$arrArguments['saleData']['orderData'][0]['description'] = 'abcdef';
$arrArguments['saleData']['orderData'][0]['price'] = 18819;
$arrArguments['saleData']['orderData'][0]['quantity'] = 24389;
$arrArguments['saleData']['orderData'][0]['vatCode'] = 'abcdef';

$restUrl ='/saleData/orderData';
new Ajax.Request("<?php echo $this->getUrl($restUrl) ?>", {
                  method: 'Post',
                  parameters: {
                     "saledata" :$arrArguments['saleData']
                               },
                  onComplete: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);  
                  }
              });
```

if you are using java/php  as a back-end language then you get request parameter to get data .

for java :-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saleData/orderData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> beforeEdit(HttpServletRequest request,HttpSession session) {
    Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
    String requestString = request.getParameter("saledata");//----may this change according to your json parsar 

}
```

for php

```
    $saledata = $this->getRequest()->getParam('saledata');
```

Comment: I think the client should be in Java (and the server is done already in PHP).

Comment: This is not really what I meant. I need to call this API from Java. The example I added was an example how to do it in PHP but I need to know how to do this in Java using the Apache HTTP client.